# Logging PHP objects

Tags: php, sqlite

I am writing a server in PHP where I want to log all database queries in a file. Now, I am using `SQLite3Stmt::bindParam` and `SQLite3::prepare` which returns a `SQLite3Stmt` object. How do I convert the `SQLite3Stmt` object to a query string so that I can log it?
I am using [KLogger](http://codefury.net/projects/klogger/) for logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do it, so I ended up logging all parameters individually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's gonna happen.  There's no methods or properties that I see in the [SQLite3 class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php), the [SQLite3Stmt class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3stmt.php), or the [SQLite3Result class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php) that support getting the processed query text back out after the parameters have been substituted in.

You'll just have to log the text and parameters separately.

Comment: I kind of expected that. Just wanted to make sure there is no other way that I am missing.